# Extending dumb components for app specific purposes

Tags: angular, inheritance, components

Now that I have heard of component inheritance available in [Angular 2.3](https://scotch.io/tutorials/component-inheritance-in-angular-2) I have been wondering how this should fit into the dumb and smart components paradigm.

Let's say, I have a dumb `dropdown-component` whose sole purpose is to display what's been delivered on its Input and provide the interaction behaviors.

But then, I decide that in many sections of the app I need to show, say, just a list of users with admin privileges. My way of thinking would be to create an app-specific dropdown class that's responsible for showing this particular list, like:

```
export class AdminUserDropdown extends Dropdown {
// logic to pull data for these users only
}
```

This would require though some logic on that component's code. Would that be ok from the paradigm's perspective? Or is there another approach more suitable for that purpose?

Comment: I don't see how this is related to dumb/smart components. I think you should strive to have dumb components that only know how to render certain data but other code should be in model classes or services. To me that's not related to inheritance with components.

Comment: So how would you solve this particular example, where you need a control with very specific purpose across the entire app?

Comment: By binding a different array to the controls `values` property (or whatever name the property has.

Comment: Wouldn't you like to have a specific component that already knows its data source (such as ngrx/store selector or specific api URL)?

Comment: I don't see much use for that. In my experience such specialized components usually won't be used more than once. Your mileage might vary of course. If you have a lot such components that show the same thing in several different places such specialized components might make sense. I's use encapsulation instead of inheritance. Event though inheritance is now supported, doesn't mean you should use it. My understanding is that Misko wasn't too keen to add that, but because so many requested it it was finally added.